# How to detect input-text pressed key on javascript

Tags: javascript, keypress

I have this simple document:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <body>
        <input id="mytext" onkeypress="myfun(e)"></input>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script> function myfun(e){ 
                if(e.keyCode==13) alert('Enter Key Pressed');}
        });
        </script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

what I want is: 
when user press enter key on mytext, show an alert to inform the user like this message : `Enter Key Pressed`

I did every thing like above, But it doesn't work and no any alert is shown when enter pressed on mytext.

**Help Please!..**

Comment: there is no closing tag for `<input>` besides many other typo errors in your  script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works when you replace myfun(e) with myfun(event). I also corrected some syntactical errors.

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <input id="mytext" onkeypress="myfun(event)"></input>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script> 
            function myfun(e){ 
                    if(e.keyCode==13) alert('Enter Key Pressed');
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Input elements are self-closing - there should not be a closing input tag.

Comment: thank you so much, this work correctly. But what is the need for <p id="demo"></p> tag that you added ?..

Comment: @SaddamMeshaal I did no add the <p id.. > tag. It's in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener to listen for the `onkeypress` event:

```
document.getElementById('mytext').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert('Enter Key Pressed');
});
```

Also, input tag's don't have a closing tag. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/r3tsz78n/) a live example

If you want to call it inline as a handler, try this:

```html
<input id="mytext" onkeypress="myfun(event)">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myfun(event){ 
    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if(key === 13) alert('Enter Key Pressed');
}
</script>
```

You must use `event` as a parameter to make sure it works correctly as a handler. Now, get's the key code and check if it's 13, then alerts.