# Javascript guide - change onclick to onkeypress-- how can I use the space key for both functions. To close the nav and open

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Just started learning HTML/css/javascript within the last 4 days.

I'm having an issue with my page. Right now I have the `onlick` function on my page on previous user button.

How can I change from `onclick` button to `onkeypress`?

Hoping the page can slide on a specific key command instead of a click.

```
    <script>
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("users").style.width = "100%";
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("users").style.width = "0%";
        }
    </script>

    <div id="users" class="loggedusers">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#">Previous logged Users</a> 
        <div id="previoususer">
            <span style="font-size:35px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&rArr; Previous Users</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.com, first, there is 3 types of keyboard events: onkeypress, onkeyup,onkeydown

https://stackoverflow.com/a/929739/494344

and for handling events see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39303058/494344

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keypress` event for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

E.g:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('log');

input.addEventListener('keypress', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  log.textContent += ` ${e.code}`;
  if(e.code == 'ArrowLeft') {
    //Slide to the left
  }
  if(e.code == 'ArrowRight') {
    //Slide to the right
  }
}
```

With `e.code` you can query the pressed key. Examples:

```
ArrowUp
ArrowLeft
ArrowRight
ArrowDown
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your whole page to react on a keypress-event instead just a input field, you can use this:

```js
    document.onkeypress =  keyPressFunction;
    function keyPressFunction(e){
        // here comes your keypress-code
        var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode
        console.log(charCode);
    }
```

Just put this snippet inside your script-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Like `onclick` there are three kinds of keyboard events. `onkeydown`, `onkeyup` and `onkeypress`.

- `onkeydown`emits when user press a button (the press only)
- `onkeyup` emits when user release the button
- `onkeypress` emits when user press a button

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `keypress` event on window and call the function inside `if statements` when user press specific key.

```
   function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("users").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("users").style.width = "0%";
    }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 38) { 
            closeNav(); // this function will be executed when user press Arrow Up key 
        }else if(e.keyCode === 40) {
            openNav(); // this function will be executed when user press Arrow Down key
        }
    });
```

Here, `window.addEventListener` execute the function which is inside of it when user presses a key. 
And  if statements will call the `closeNav()` function if Arrow Up is pressed  and will call `openNav()` function if Arrow Down is pressed.
if other keys are pressed if statements will not run.

Comment: I can't use the same keys to open and close ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Keyboard Events

In javascript we have three keyboard event

1. `keydown`
2. `keypress`
3. `keyup`

triggered exactly in this order.

*in my opinion the best way to work with keyboard navigation is to use the "keydown" event as in the Sandesh's example.*

## Handling events

To handle these events you have 3 way: (examples for "keydown")

**1. in markup**

```html
<element onkeydown="myScript">
```

**2. javascript `element.onkeydown`**

```
object.onkeydown = function(){myScript};
```

**3. javascript `element.addEventListener`**

```
object.addEventListener("keydown", myScript);
```

Due to security issue the best way is to use the third. (you can get more information googling 'XSS' or 'cross site scripting') Infact to prevent XSS in your site you need to add some http headers that block inline scripts ([CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)).

furthermore you can pass `true` to the third parameter of `addEventListener` method to capture the event before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree and then you can stop propagation if the key code matches the reserved one. It depends on the user experience that you want to implement.

## Keycodes

Try this site to get keycodes: [keycode.info](https://keycode.info/)

in my opinion, for your case the best way is to use `event.code`.

## Resources:

[MDN - keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)

[MDN - addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)